# Reset(clear) input fields JS/HTML with button "clean"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button

I have 1 input field, 1 dropdown menu and a datepicker field. So I made a function resetFields() which sets the value to empty string "". The information clears but for example if I choose a new date or other option in the select menu the old information comes back in the fields. How can I fully clear it ? The project is on VueJS

```
<input v-model="filter.number" placeholder="Number" id="number">
<select v-model="filter.type" style="width: 209px; float: right;" id="type">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</select>

<datepicker v-model="filter.date1" placeholder="Choose date" :format="DatePickerFormat" id="date1"></datepicker>
<button style="height: 30px;" @click="resetFields()">Clean</button> 

resetFields(){ 
    var number = document.getElementById('number'); 
    var type= document.getElementById('type'); 
    var date1 = document.getElementById('date1'); 
    number.value = ""; 
    type.value = ""; 
    date1.value = ""; 
}
```

***Updated***

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

This is my Vue instance

***Update2:***

```
Data.vue
<input v-model="filter.number" placeholder="Number">

<button @click="resetFields()">Clear</button>

main.js

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        filter: {
          eori: null,
          docSubType: null,
          data1: null
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      resetFields () {
        this.eori = null
        this.docSubType = null
        this.data1 = null
      }
    },
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

and with your code example doesn't work.

***Update3***

Comment: I don't know if you know it, but... there is a button in html form that reset your inputs automatically, [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

Comment: The variable definition and value assignment doesn't match

Comment: It was a typo @KrishnaPrashatt. Fixed

Comment: @Decrux Is that the whole of Data.vue file?

Comment: Nope, there are about 15 input fields, 3 selects and <model-selects> and 2-3 datepickers. There is a dynamic rendered table too. Tell what you need from me to provide.

Comment: @Decrux I need to see `<script>` tag of Data.vue component.

Comment: Update3, first post

Comment: @Decrux I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code responsible for clearing fields should be in the component where the fields are defined. Add a `resetFields` function under `methods` object of your Data.vue component.

```js
/* .. */
methods: {
  /* ... */
  resetFields() {
    this.filter.eori = ''
    this.filter.docSubType = ''
    this.filter.data1 = ''

    // Or just clear all object's properties
    Object.keys(this.filter).forEach(key => { 
      this.filter[key] = ''
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working for me... I will update my first post

Comment: Updated @Konrad Kalemba

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Pin: <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4"><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click on the reset button to reset the form.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The input type reset is a native implementation for form resets

Comment: Just tried, it's working but not very well. I have some <model-select> which is not working at all with it(it's not showing now?). The other select menus the 0 option is for example A, and I need to clear it fully.

Comment: And for that you need to use vue, maybe you can dispatch and event and react to it by clearing the field

Comment: Can you help me for Vue? The project is on Vue by the way

Answer (score -1):

change 1:
add onclick="resetFields()" in ur button tag instead of @click=resetField()

change 2: add jquery CDN to your HTML code just above  tag
https://code.jquery.com/

change 3: add a script tag in the same HTML as below:
    function resetFields(){$("#number").val("")}

You can use javascript also.

thanks

## bangthugs

Comment: There is definitely no need for that big library like jQuery for such simple task. Especially when Vue is used.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. :)